# Parallel Solution to Linear Systems

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I have the linear system of the following type
$$\begin{align}
x_1 &= a_0, \\
x_2 &= a_1x_1, \\
x_3 &= a_3x_2 + a_2x_1, \\
&\vdots \\
x_n &= a_{j}x_{n-1} + \dots + a_{k}x_1,
\end{align}$$
where all $a_i$ are known constants. This can clearly be solved through recursion, with a cost of $\mathcal{O}(n)$, but I was wondering if there exists any (possibly approximate) solutions to do this in faster time?

Comment: This takes $\mathcal O(n^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faster than $\mathcal O(n)$ is not possible as there are $n$ variables to evaluate.